# Placeholder in input field doesn't react to padding

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the input field wider and taller while creating some spacing between the borders and placeholder text.

```
.modal-body input {
   border-radius: 6px;
   border: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
   padding: 16px;
}
```

```
<input type="text"
   name="projectName"
   value="{{ Project.name }}"
   class="form-control"
   id="projectName"
   placeholder="E.g. Skyscraper 9"
   data-rule-required="true"
   data-msg="{% trans %}Please enter a Project Name{% endtrans %}"
   data-rule-minlength="3"
   data-msg-minlength="{% trans %}Project Name needs to be at least 3 characters{% endtrans %}">
```

But it just ends up looking like this
[Padding is overlapping the placeholder text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH6gL.png)

Comment: The issue is, when I turn your code into a snippet (which you should try: it's the `<>` button in the editor of Stack Overflow), this is not the case! So this means that in all likelihood _something else_ is fixing the `height` of your input and setting it's `box-sizing` to `border-box`, which would produce this effect. But with the code provided, this is just not the case and the padding gets correctly applied. So in short, there's too little info to actually debug your issue here.

Comment: Is that your html?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.